# Adding elements using jQuery on document.ready and then making changes to freshly added elements

Tags: jquery

If you add elements using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // append new div somewhere
}
```

how can I check if that newly created div (after document was ready) was clicked? 
Because this does not seem to work:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       // append new div somewhere with "test" class
     $(".test").click( function(){
           // do things
      });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Method 'on' should be used here. It attaches an event to existing elements and also to the elements that could be added later. You can also check the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

This code should solve your issue:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class-of-newly-added-element', function(e) {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: No problems, though i recommend searching StackOverflow before posting questions, because this question was already asked. Mark this answer as accepted if that helped.:)

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
$('.test').live('click', function (){
  //code here
});
```

or

```
$('.test').on('click', function (){
  //code here
});
```

Note: live() is deprecated As of jQuery 1.7

Comment: @Downvoter: Drop your comments to improve the answer